# Can we find a field, if we have a group?

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, group-isomorphism

1. Lets be $(G,\oplus)$ a group isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R},+)$. Can we find an operator "$\odot$" so that $(G,\odot,\oplus)$ is field?
2. Lets be $(G,\odot)$ a group isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R}^\ast,\cdot)$. Can we find an operator "$\oplus$" and a number "$e$"  so that $(G\cup\{e\},\odot,\oplus)$ is field?
3. Is there any bibliography about these properties?

**For example:**
Lets be $a\odot b=5ab$ for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^\ast$. Then it is easy to see that we can find an operator "$\oplus$" and a number "$e$" ("$\oplus$" is "$+$" and $e=0$) so that $(\mathbb{R}^\ast \cup \{e\},\odot,\oplus)$ is field.
**But what about other choices?** If "$\odot$" was "$+$" or $a\odot b=a+b+ab$, then what?

Comment: The answer to the title question is no in general, because finite subgroups of $(K^{\times},\cdot)$ must be cyclic. So take any non-cyclic finite group. But for $G=\Bbb R$ we can find it. It is just $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Let $f:G\rightarrow\Bbb R$ be an isomorphism of additive groups. Define $$\odot:G\times G\xrightarrow{f\times f}\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\xrightarrow{\cdot}\Bbb R\xrightarrow{f^{-1}}G.$$
   We can check that this makes $G$ a field, with multiplicative unit $f^{-1}(1)$.
2. Let $f:G\rightarrow\Bbb R^*$ be an isomorphism of multiplicative groups. Let $e$ be a symbol, and extend $\odot$ to $G\cup\{e\}$ by $g\cdot e=e\cdot g=e$. Then $G\cup\{e\}$ is a monoid. Extend $f$ to $(G\cup\{e\})$ by $f(e)=0$. $f$ is now an isomorphism of monoids, from $G\cup\{e\}$ to $\Bbb R^*\cup\{0\}=\Bbb R$. Define
   $$\oplus:(G\cup\{e\})\times (G\cup\{e\})\xrightarrow{f\times f}\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\xrightarrow{+}\Bbb R\xrightarrow{f^{-1}}(G\cup\{e\}).$$
   We can check that this makes $(G\cup\{e\})$ a field, with additive unit $e$.

Comment: thanks a lot! Very helpful your answer!

Comment: I believe that you mean $g\cdot e=e\cdot g$ not $g\cdot e=e\cdot g=e$. Am I correct?

Comment: $e$ is our $0$, and we need to define the image of these two products, so I send them both to $e$.

Comment: sure. My mistake.

Answer (score 3):

What if you set $g_1 \odot g_2 = f^{-1}[f(g_1)\cdot_{\mathbb{R}}f(g_2)]$

and

$g_1 +_G g_2 = f^{-1}[f(g_1)+_{\mathbb{R}} f(g_2)] $

where $f$ is the isomorphism.

Comment: Those aren't operations internal to $G$, but I think it's the right idea.

Comment: thanks! you're right

Comment: @ΓιάννηςΠαπαβασιλείου , ευχαριστώ πολύ για την βοήθεια. Συγγνώμη για το τσεκάρισμα ως απαντηθέν μιας άλλης απάντησης. Το έκανα επειδή ήταν λίγο πιο αναλυτική, αν και η δικιά σας απάντηση ήταν πιο ευπαρουσίαστη.

Comment: @Kώστας Κούδας  Μια χαρά, κανένα πρόβλημα